# Not getting solution to draw heatmap using amcharts on floor map image

Tags: angular, heatmap, amcharts

I want to draw **heatmap** on **floor map** image, using **amcharts** in **angular 8**. But not getting proper examples, I want to show occupancy level in floor using heat map.

Any example or suggestions Really appreciated.

Thanks,